# Bootstrap Scrollspy Navigate when clicking on dropdown

Tags: javascript, navigation

Is there a way to incorporate navigate the moment you click on a dropdown? Id like the page to navigate to section 4 upon clicking section for on the navigation bar and then if the user decides to navigate further from the list, they can by clicking on an item from the list. Thanks!

```
<li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Section 4<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#section42">Section 4-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section42">Section 4-2</a></li>           
      </ul>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap documentation provides exactly what you're looking for, please have a look :

[Bootstrap scrollspy on navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/scrollspy/#example-in-navbar)

Comment: I have looked here but did not find it, hence why I posted. Can you point me in the right direction? Thanks!